# Is it on-topic to ask if the way I want to write a character is plausible?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I do not identify as LGBTQ+, but I am going to be writing a book with a main character who is. Their queerness will only be prominent for one arc, during which the story will focus very heavily on their internal thoughts and feelings, specifically relating to them being queer. There is a specific development I would like them to undergo, but I don't know whether it's a plausible one or not since I'm not queer myself.

**Would it be on-topic to explain my potential arc on the Writing SE and ask if it's a plausible one?**

I've read the two help-center pages about what questions count as on-topic, but none of the bullet points seem to address this. The best evidence I can gather is below.

Evidence in favor, from [What topics can I ask about here?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Questions on these topics are welcome here:
>
> - Writing fiction, poetry, scripts, or song lyrics.
> - Questions asking for help expressing a concept or an idea, within limits.
> - [...]

Evidence against, from [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you're asking too much.

But in my opinion, none of these settle the issue decisively.

Comment: I think these are good examples to emulate:
- https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/18950/how-to-do-research-to-write-characters-from-a-different-culture 
- https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/39373/how-to-write-internally-emotional-characters

Answer (score 1):

In my personal opinion, this is **probably on-topic** as long as you narrow it to a specific type of question that falls within Writing SE's scope, such as character development or plot development.

That is, it would count as "asking for help expressing a concept or idea" if you marked it as asking specifically about character development or plot development as it pertains to this character - i.e. you could frame it as asking how best to execute the specific kind of plotline you want with this character, instead of just generally asking "is this plot good," which would be off-topic.

I once asked a question about how to properly write a scene involving a transgender character and their character development, and it was not marked as off-topic and was given some very thoughtful and helpful answers. And speaking as an LGBTQ+ person myself, I'd be thrilled to give you advice on this kind of question.

Comment: In world building, we call this a reality check. It might make a good tag